# Show no unique numbers in $\pmod m$ can have the same multiplicative inverse if $m$ isn't prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am wondering whether  unique numbers in $\pmod m$ can have the same multiplicative inverse where $m$ isn't prime (I have proved that if $m$ is prime, this is impossible). I feel intuitively that this is impossible because it would somehow imply that these 2 numbers with the same inverse are congruent $\pmod m$ and not unique. However, I have been struggling to show this. The crux of the matter seems to be whether if I have $c \equiv c \pmod m$ where $c$ is any integer, and $a \not\equiv b \pmod m $, is $ca \not\equiv cb \pmod m$ necessarily the case? This relates to my question because $c$ could be the shared inverse, and $a$ and $b$ the unique numbers in modulo $m$. I would appreciate how to show this.

Comment: The usual proof of unique inverses works in rings (with $1$), not just fields (or if these terms are unfamiliar, with any modulus, not just prime ones). In particular, suppose $a$ has two inverses $b$ and $c$, and try computing $bac$ in two ways, using associativity.

Comment: You're asking if $c$ is cancellable modulo $m$. By the dupe: $c$ is cancellable iff $c$ is invertible iff $c$ is coprime $m,$ see the proofs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of the inverse of $x$ is $x$, so you can't ever have different things with the same inverse.  I suspect your question is not really about inverses, though: in the integers mod $m$, only those residues coprime to $m$ form a multiplicative group and have inverses.  The others do not.

For example, in the integers mod $6$ we have $2 \not\equiv 4 \pmod 6$ but $3 \times 2 \equiv 3 \times 4 \equiv 0 \pmod 6$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).